# Make HTML canvas as image source fit the aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, responsive-images, todataurl

I am currently trying to make a pictionary application in HTML/CSS/PHP and after making the application I am trying to make it mobile friendly/responsive.

The way I am displaying the canvas that is being drawn on on the other players' screen is this:

**javascript**

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    let base64dotpng = canvas.toDataURL();
    ws.send("canvas:" + base64dotpng);
```

Which I am sending over a websocket. This works perfectly fine and when I read the data back in like this:

```
let ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext('2d');
let canvasImage = new Image();
canvasImage.src = msg;
if (newRound) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth * 0.525, window.innerHeight * 0.90);
}
ctx.drawImage(canvasImage, 0, 0);
```

However now that I'm implementing a mobile version whenever I load in a canvas on mobile the ratio of the canvas is a bit different and it does not load the full image.

**css**

This is my css on general vs mobile:

general:

```
#drawingCanvas {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: white;
        border-width: 0.3vh;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        position: absolute;
        height: 90vh;
        top: 5vh;
        left: 20vw;
        width: 52.5vw;
    }
```

mobile:

```
canvas#drawingCanvas {
            z-index: 1;
            top: 0;
            margin-left: -20%;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 52.5%;
            height: 99%;
        }
```

If the canvas was to be stretched on mobile that would be fine, but right now this is the difference:

[how it is being drawn on a computer browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58sVQ.png)

vs

[how it is getting displayed on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPcCX.png)
(the phone is in landscape mode)

So the canvas appears to be loading in at full size

Thanks in advance,

Aap.

Comment: Please try to set the canvas width and height in javascript not in the CSS. For 100% width you may use `canvas.width = window.innerWidth` and for 100% height you may use `canvas.height = window.innerHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer in the `.drawImage` method of `context`.

The 4th and 5th parameters can be used to rescale the canvas like so:

```
  if (isMobile){
        ctx.drawImage(canvasImage, 0,0,canvasImage.width*(window.innerWidth / (canvasImage.width/0.525)),canvasImage.height*(window.innerHeight/(canvasImage.height/0.9)));
    } else {
        ctx.drawImage(canvasImage, 0, 0);
    }
```